# Trigger jenkins build on tfs pull request

Tags: jenkins, pull-request

How do i get TFS to trigger a jenkins build when a pull request is created? it would be a smoketest, to make sure everything works before merging with main.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Team Foundation Server plugin for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md). Integrate TFS as a git repository.

check the checkbox next to Enable Push Trigger for all jobs in the Jenkins global configuration